# How to show a list of validation error messages out of a datagrid row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Is there any way of showing all validation messages outside of a datagrid?
If you run several validationrow rules and get more than one message, a sad tooltip in the rowheader is not enough. I'd rather prefer another datagrid to show all these messages (or any other "ItemsControl"). I've tried with validation.error event on datagrid (with a dataset bounded) but it doesn't trigger. How can I bind the ItemSource to the actual ErrorContent in such datagrid?
"ValidationAdornerSite" apparently works, but its placeholder is in the rowheader and not in the place I'd like to...
I've also tried the methods given in [WPF 3.5 SP1 Feature: BindingGroups with Item-level Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-bindinggroups-with-item-level-validation) and works great, but not for datagrid

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was speak out loud the question and the answer came, so, for the sake of this question I'm describing the mistakes and misunderstanding I made, and how eventually achieved my goal by putting all things together in the proper way *at the same time*:

1. First mistake: Use BindingGroup in datagrid instead ItemBindingGroup. This allows you use NotifyOnValidationError attibute, so Validation.Error event triggers normally. You can then forget DataGrid.RowValidationRules, because your should put your validation rules inside the BindingGroup object in ItemBindingGroup.
2. Whereas Validation.Error handler can be defined in Datagrid, Validation.ValidationAdornerSite should be defined in the BindingGroup object.
3. Don't use UpdateSourceTrigger attribute in any binding of the BindingGroup. This was a misunderstanding I did that provokes a *erratic* behaviour because BindingGroup will ignore these bindings and the Binding will update the source on their own.

This is the code I use to put all things together in the proper way:

Define Datagrid and ItemBindigGroup

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WinViewSource}}" 
          Validation.Error="BindingGroup_Error" >

    <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup NotifyOnValidationError="True" ValidatesOnNotifyDataError="True" Validation.ValidationAdornerSite="{Binding ElementName=ErrorListBox}" >
            <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                <YourValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False"/>
            </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
        </BindingGroup>
    </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>

    <...>
        
</DataGrid>
<ListBox Name="ErrorListBox" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxErrorStyle}" Button.Click="GoToErrorButton_Click"/>
```

The style of ListBox for ValidationAdornerSite.

```
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding (Validation.ValidationAdornerSiteFor).(Validation.Errors), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="LightYellow">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Go to" Visibility="{Binding ErrorContent.ButtonGoToVisibility}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorContent.ErrorCode}" Margin="3"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=ErrorContent.ErrorMessage}" Margin="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Binding ItemsSource to Validation.Errors is not enough because although anytime there is a validation error, ListBox checks the last ListViewItem for Validation.Errors, It'll be precisely the *last* ListViewItem and not the *current* ListViewItem. To avoid this you need Validation.Error event in order to *reattach*:

```
  Private Sub BindingGroup_Error(sender As Object, e As ValidationErrorEventArgs)

     Validation.SetValidationAdornerSite(DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, DependencyObject), ErrorListBox)

  End Sub
```

My client requirement includes a very simple object as ErrorContent with 3 properties, which values should be defined in the Validation rule, in order to go to the *cause* of the error:

```
   Public Class ErrorContent
      Public Property ErrorCode As String
      Public Property ErrorMessage As String
      Public Property ButtonGoToVisibility As Visibility = Visibility.Visible
   End Class
```

By having the above you'll see all your validation errors in a list wherever you want in the screen, and the user can have better experience handling them.